# Rails 5 validate parameters based on current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Product model which belongs_to a Category. A User only has access to a few categories.

How do I validate when creating a Product, that the User has access to the `category_id` it is trying to assign?

Let's assume I have the list of allowed Categories in `session[:category_ids]`.

In the controller I use strong parameters like so:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :category_id)
end
```

Is it possible to filter out values we dont have access to here? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The list of allowed categories exists only in the session?

Comment: Why don't you just do `before_action` and check if current_user has access to specific category? I'm not sure if you should store it in session at all...

Comment: The session is just an example. They can be retrieved from the user object. I was trying to prevent having to filter params in 2 places: once with the require and permit methods, and additional filtering in a before_action. Doesn't feel like keeping it DRY :)

Answer (score 1):

In your products_controller add

`before_action :require_category_access`

in your Product model create some function that checks to see if the user has access to the correct categories which will run before the data is saved.

```
def require_category_access
  if current_user <has access to the category>
    return true
  else
    redirect_to some_url 
    flash[:error] = "no access for you"
  end
end
```

Comment: We are not accessing the category as a resource. Instead, we are assigning it to a Product object via the incoming params object. Is it then still best practice to iterate through the params object in a before_action? It would be so much nicer if the params object would support this in its `permit` or `require` methods.